# Class (object) needs 1 positional argument what should I put there

Tags: python, macos, class, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make a cookieclicker bot and I've put all my functions in a class. I am using all my variables I just didn't paste in the whole class. I've tried deleting the object and paranthesis but then nothing worked and now I'm stuck.

Code:

```
def COOKIEBOT2000(object):
    def __init__(self,upgrade=1,click=1,prints=0):
        self.upgrade = upgrade
        self.click = click
        self.prints = prints
    def Clicker(self):
        if self.click == 1:
            click = driver.find_element_by_id("bigCookie")
            click.click()
            if self.prints == 1:
                click = driver.find_element_by_id("cookies")
                click.click()
                click = click.text
                money = click.split("\n")
                money = money[0].split(" ")
                money = int(money[0])
                print (money)
COOKIEBOT = COOKIEBOT2000()
COOKIEBOT.Clicker()
```

And it then returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/Moltas/Documents/Py stuff/coockie.py", line 57, in <module>
        COOKIEBOT = COOKIEBOT2000()
TypeError: COOKIEBOT2000() missing 1 required positional argument: 'object'
```

My Question is what am I supposed to put as a postitional argument?

Comment: Your "class" is a function. Change `def COOKIEBOT2000` to `class COOKIEBOT2000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
class COOKIEBOT2000(object):
    def __init__(self,upgrade=1,click=1,prints=0):
        self.upgrade = upgrade
        self.click = click
        self.prints = prints
    def Clicker(self):
        if self.click == 1:
            click = driver.find_element_by_id("bigCookie")
            click.click()
            if self.prints == 1:
                click = driver.find_element_by_id("cookies")
                click.click()
                click = click.text
                money = click.split("\n")
                money = money[0].split(" ")
                money = int(money[0])
                print (money)
COOKIEBOT = COOKIEBOT2000()
COOKIEBOT.Clicker()
```